# CSS Dropdown on navigation elements

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have a navigation bar I've built with a few links in it (using a ul with li and anchors) and I'm trying to figure out how to make certain links dropdowns with more links inside of them.  I tried following the w3schools example of dropdowns but it seems like my links are just "scrunching" together.  Here's the code:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav-container">
  <ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Climb</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="">Link 1</a>
            <a href="">Link 2</a>
            <a href="">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

What it looks like on my end is that the links are all scrunched together.  I want it so that the dropdown appears on hover (so, display changes from none to block), but the actual content of the dropdown is appearing inline with the navigation links instead of underneath like it should be.  What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ggpeww?file=style.css) for you. Is this what you're looking for?
You can make you content `display: flex;` while using `flex-direction: column;` instead of `display: block;`.

Comment: Not really.. the problem I have is that the dropdown links are not going *underneath* my main nav link. They are scrunching up side-by-side with it..

Comment: what do you mean underneath? could you please draw what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dropdowns to animate in and out eventually, you'll need to use javascript unless you're a real css wizard. Basically, you'll add a `visible` class on mouseenter that changes the dropdown from `display: none` to `display: block` and sets the starting state of your animation, like `opacity: 0`. Then, after a `requestAnimationFrame`, you add an `in` class that sets the final state of your animation, like `opacity: 1`. The requestAnimationFrame is needed because going from `none` to `block` causes the browser to cancel any css animations.

The close animation is the same principle: you remove the `in` class on mouseout, then after a timeout for however long your animation is, you remove the `visible` class.